# White Page Bug with ASP.Net and Datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource, objectdatasource

I am using a Datalist using SqlDatasource on a usercontrol. Below is the html

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlFeaturedCatalogs" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" Width="100%"
                                        Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False"
                                        Font-Underline="False" ShowFooter="False" CellPadding="4" 
                                        ForeColor="#333333" DataSourceID="FCDatasource" 
                                        DataKeyField="Id">
                                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                        <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                        <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-left: 5px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 11px">
                                                        <asp:Image ID="imgList" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl="~/images/company.jpg" />
                                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlCategory" ForeColor="#005aa3" Font-Underline="false" runat="server"
                                                            NavigateUrl='<%# ResolveUrl(string.Format("~/BusinessBazaarAspx/CompDetls.aspx?cid={0}&name={1}",Common.EncodeTo64(Eval("Id").ToString()),Common.EncodeTo64(Eval("Name").ToString()) )) %>'
                                                            Text=' <%#Eval("Name") %>' Target="_blank"> </asp:HyperLink>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:DataList>

                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="FCDatasource" runat="server" 
                                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BusinessBazaarConnectionString %>" 
                                SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyId], [CompanyName] FROM [tbl_Company] ORDER BY [CompanyName]">
                            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am not using any serverside code. Whenever I use to run it the parent page becomes entire white. Why????

**Update**

Final result i am getting, I have lots of user controls and databinding there. No thing rendering. Seems entire page viewstate is going false.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put at least `Response.Write("Test");` in the Page_Load on the server side code, do you see this in the browser?

could it be that you are returning no records from the database?

Comment: my page has lots of controls...   the final result i am getting is this <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>

Comment: @Davide Piras: Would be better as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

("I am not using any serverside code" that's not true, but nvm.)

try using this in a simple label or something, and after it works add the images and hyperlinks, dont try to do complicated stuff, do it step-by-step:

```
Text=' <%#Eval("Name") %>'
```

or

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>'
```

Also, binding the datasource would be easier to do/test in code-behind.